# Java array declaration in multiple lines.

Tags: java, arrays

Hi!

I'm just beginning to learn Java and i was wondering if how is it possible to put array elements in multiple lines when declaring an array.

The following code gives me an error:

```
public String[] songList = {'Stadium Arcadium', 'Make You Feel Better', 'Under The Bridge',
       'Wet Sand', 'Californication', 'Charlie', 'Aeroplane', 'Transcending', 'Ethiopia'};
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: single quotes are for chars...please google before posting

Comment: It is always a good idea to include error text to your question. Strings should be put into `"`, not `'`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can put your strings on multiple lines.

However, use double-quotes to surround your String literals:

```
public String[] songList = {"Stadium Arcadium", "Make You Feel Better", "Under The Bridge",
       "Wet Sand", "Californication", "Charlie", "Aeroplane", "Transcending", "Ethiopia"};
```

Here's a link about [String literals](http://java.about.com/od/understandingdatatypes/a/The-String-Literal.htm)

Comment: Thank you. I feel quite stupid, since i've previously programmed only in Python so i didn't cross my mind that sigle and double quotes might have a difference in Java.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with declaring array elements in multiple lines  its with **HOW YOU DECLARING YOUR ARRAY ELEMNTS**

 see you have array type as `String` and `String` types need to be enclosed in `" "` (double quotes) not in single quotes (which are for characters)

just declare your array as:
`public String[] songList = {"Stadium Arcadium", "Make You Feel Better", "Under The Bridge",
       "Wet Sand", "Californication", "Charlie", "Aeroplane", "Transcending", "Ethiopia"};`